# Can't upload file using Watir, Headless Browser, Chromedriver, using Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, cloud9

I am trying to automate the creation of a listing on my website and I am having a lot of difficulty uploading an image for the listing. I am using Cloud9 and Watir, and using a headless chrome browser and the code is written in Ruby. For some reason the photo refuses to upload.

[Click to see picture of upload area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUyv0.png)

```
photo = File.open("00909_8qYJaR8wTix_600x450.jpg", "a") 
path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(photo))
browser.file_field(:type,"file").set(path)
```

Output on terminal:

```
[8] pry(main)> browser.file_field(:type,"file").value
=> ""
[9] pry(main)> path
=> "/home/ubuntu/workspace/scraper"
[10] pry(main)> File.exist? (path)
=> true
```

HTML
    input class="fileupload" multiple="multiple" type="file" style="display: 
    inline-block;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't `path` variable contain the path to actual file? From your example it looks like it's pointing to parent directory. Ditch the `File.dirname(photo)` turning it to this:

```
photo = File.open("00909_8qYJaR8wTix_600x450.jpg", "a") 
path = File.expand_path(photo)
browser.file_field(:type,"file").set(path)
```

and you should be fine, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I was under the impression that the path code was returning it, but apparently not!